# Magento configurable swatch (1.9.1 native) not switching image in main product page

Tags: magento

I couldn't figure what's wrong but the native configurable swatch no longer work, it won't change the product image when different option is selected. I have tried the catalog page option and it worked, jus the main product page. Can anyone please take a look?
http://store.yocupco.com/yogurtcups/16-oz-paper-yogurt-cups.html

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict with "Onepage check out" from IWD indeed. However you don't need to uninstall it.
Just login to Admin Panel, go to 'System', 'IWD Extensions', 'Core' and set 'enable jQuery on frontend' to NO. That worked for me with Magento 1.9.1.1

Answer (score -1):

In http://store.yocupco.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js file find

`image.elevateZoom();`

and replace it with

`if (jQuery('.product-image').length == 0) {
    image.elevateZoom();
}`

Comment: Hi, I added your code to the app.js file and it has solved the image not switching problem, however, the zoom function is still lost. After multiple tries, I have identified the problem to be associated with an extension called "Onepage check out", uninstalling it solved the problem entirely. Thanks again for the help!